# Complete password- and key-less login for user using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, user-accounts

I want to use [this plugin](https://github.com/SiebelsTim/hack-sublime) in my text editor to debug my [HHVM](http://hhvm.com) application. Therefore I need a Linux user which is able to login via SSH both without password and without key authentication.

How can I achieve this?

I tried several ways, including

```
passwd -d hhvm-debuguser
```

But then, I can’t login; I entered nothing when I was being asked for password:

```
main@faraway:~$ su hhvm-debuguser
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

My SSH config file looks like this, only allowing the user `hhvm-debuguser` from my personal IP:

```
DenyUsers hhvm-debuguser

Match User hhvm-debuguser Address my.ip.address.home
    PermitEmptyPasswords yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowUsers hhvm-debuguser
```

*(Yes, I know that this is an absolute edge-use-case which should not be used in the wild and I'm aware of the risks and security isses)*

Comment: *therefore* I need ... without key authentication.  I don't follow why this plugin requires no key authentication.

Comment: Reading the readme file under your link, you need to set up passwordless login, it doesn't matter if passwords are still enabled, and you don't want to denyUser in shh config.  What it wants is to be able to login without a password.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 or more problem here. but start from first.

You need to specify as below for allowed user. you dont need to explicitly define block user just remove them from AllowUsers

AllowUsers syed@IP

Than.
you have two options

Host based AUthentication.
RhostsRSAAuthentication

One more hack than can work here is tunnelier. you can authenticate and keep the tunnel open (SSH tunnel from your server to your PC and Access everything on you server as local Resource)